# PHP Trello API Post Request

Tags: php, trello

I am trying to send Post requests to my Trello Board. I tried now for many hours, but its everytime not working. I checked the code many times already and i'm not getting the problem.

I'm using that API:

```
    <?php

    class trello_api
    {
        private $key;
        private $token;

        public function __construct($key, $token)
        {
            $this->key = $key;
            $this->token = $token;
        }

        public function request($type, $request, $args = false)
        {
            if (!$args) {
                $args = array();
            } elseif (!is_array($args)) {
                $args = array($args);
            }

            if (strstr($request, '?')) {
                $url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/' . $request . '&key=' . $this->key . '&token=' . $this->token;
            } else {
                $url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/' . $request . '?key=' . $this->key . '&token=' . $this->token;
            }

            $c = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            if (count($args)) curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($args));

            switch ($type) {
                case 'POST':
                    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    break;
                case 'GET':
                    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
                    break;
                default:
                    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
            }

            $data = curl_exec($c);
            echo curl_error($c);
            curl_close($c);

            return json_decode($data);
        }
    }
```

That is my PHP Code for the Post request:

```
    $trello->request('POST', 'cards', array('name' => $card_name, 'idList' => $list_id));
```

But its not adding the Card to the list. :/
Can someone help me with my problem?